# I can't Create Data in database

Tags: php, mysqli, crud

I can't create or insert data into `mysqli_`. When I `var_dump($conn)` nothing happen. No result. Here's my code. How can I fix this?

```
<?php
// Koneksi
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","12345","mahasiswa");
// Cek apakah tombol submit
if(isset($_POST["submit"]) ) {


$nrp = $_POST["nrp"];
$nama = $_POST["nama"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$jurusan = $_POST["jurusan"];

// Query insert data
$query = "INSERT INTO daftar_mahasiswa(nrp, nama, email, jurusan)
            VALUES('$nrp','$nama','$email','$jurusan')";

mysqli_query($conn, $query);

// Cek apakah data berhasil di tambahkan
return mysql_affected_rows($conn);

}
```

I'm using ubuntu 16.04. Thanks

Comment: What errors are you getting? [How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) Also see: `mysqli_connect_error() `

Comment: too many missing parts here and you're mixing apis

Comment: *"How can i fix this"* - By debugging which you're not doing and it's all part of coding. You need to learn how to do this.